Spring framework dependency injection
I have my controller class and a instance member is annotated with @Autowired annotation. The IndexImplementer call to method2() is successfully executed when the post request is made during testing. But the instance creation of IndexImplementer is not being done via no-args constructor defined as the call to the private method is not executed (we have added logs inside the constructor as well as private methods for debugging). Also the WebController has no constructor based dependency injection done.

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    IndexImplementer indexImplementer;

    @PostMapping("/config")
    public string method1() {
        indexImplementer.method2(); 
    }

}


The IndexImplementer class is annotated with @Component annotation and contains a no-args constructor explicitly defined. Also call to private method of IndexImplementer is added in this constructor.

@Component
public class IndexImplementer {

    public IndexImplementer() {
        //call to private method 
    }

    private void method1() {
        //logic
    }

    public void method2() {
        //logic
    }

}


What we want to know is why is the instance creation for IndexImplementer class not being done via the no-args constructor defined and how to make it happen through the no-args constructor defined by us.

what you wrote doesn't make any sense. I was so surprised that I extra tested it, and on my computer method1() gets called from the constructor. Either you are debugging wrong, or your reduced code (which has compilation mistakes btw) doesn't reflect the actual code

IndexImplementer indexImplementer = new IndexImplementer(); ?

@Elikill58 even in case of manual instantiation the constructor and all of the methods within it would get called. The only thing that kind of makes sense is that there is another constructor that has @Autowired and that is the constructor that is used instead of no-args constructor

You can use the constructor base injection also,
public class WebController{
    private IndexImplementer indexImplementer;

    // Constructor that accepts an IndexImplementer object
    public WebController(IndexImplementer indexImplementer) {
        this.indexImplementer = indexImplementer;
    }
}


The code you show does not produce the behaviour you describe.
But lets see if I can give some pointers.

What we want to know is why is the instance creation for IndexImplementer class not being done via the no-args constructor defined and how to make it happen through the no-args constructor defined by us.

Despite other claims Spring does not us magic.
If it instantiates beans it calls constructors.
Since for the class in question there is only one constructor, that one will get called, if the class is instantiated by Spring.
This means you probably have another constructor which is used.
Spring may choose one of many constructors if available:

Only one constructor of any given bean class may declare @Autowired with the required attribute set to true, indicating the constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean. As a consequence, if the required attribute is left at its default value true, only a single constructor may be annotated with @Autowired. If multiple constructors declare the annotation, they will all have to declare required=false in order to be considered as candidates for autowiring (analogous to autowire=constructor in XML). The constructor with the greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching beans in the Spring container will be chosen. If none of the candidates can be satisfied, then a primary/default constructor (if present) will be used. Similarly, if a class declares multiple constructors but none of them is annotated with @Autowired, then a primary/default constructor (if present) will be used. If a class only declares a single constructor to begin with, it will always be used, even if not annotated. Note that an annotated constructor does not have to be public.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html

Also the WebController has no constructor based dependency injection done.

This seems to surprise you.
Which in turn surprises me, since how and why should Spring do constructor based dependency injection, when there is only the default constructor and the only injection point marked with @Autowired is a field thus resulting in field injection.
It sounds like you are surprised by this
